# child_process.spawn ENOENT issue in nodejs script

Tags: javascript, node.js, spawn

I am trying to run the following in a node script:

```
/bin/sh -c '/Users/edwardthompson/IdeaProjects/evidentia4/evidentia4/package/macosx/e/wkhtmltopdf --page-size "letter" --footer-center "[page] of [topage]" --footer-left "Prepared Jul 7, 2019 by Edward A Thompson" --footer-right "Evidentia(c) 2012-2017" --footer-font-size "10" --footer-font-name "Times" --print-media-type /var/folders/45/2rx5vf4j47jf4hx5157q4q800000gn/T/ResearchSummaryReport-201967122421963.html /var/folders/45/2rx5vf4j47jf4hx5157q4q800000gn/T/ResearchSummaryReport-201967122421964.pdf'
```

Running from the command line, it works fine, but I have to have the quotes around everything being passed to /bin/sh -c

When I do the same thing in a node script:

```
child = child_process.spawn('/bin/sh -c', ["'" + args.join(' ') + "'"], {stdio: 'inherit'});
```

I get:

```
Message:
Uncaught exception: Error: spawn /bin/sh -c ENOENT
Stack:
error properties: Object({ errno: 'ENOENT', code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'spawn /bin/sh -c', path: '/bin/sh -c', spawnargs: [ ''/Users/edwardthompson/IdeaProjects/evidentia4/evidentia4/package/macosx/e/wkhtmltopdf --page-size "letter" --footer-center "[page] of [topage]" --footer-left "Prepared Jul 7, 2019 by Edward A Thompson" --footer-right "Evidentia(c) 2012-2017" --footer-font-size "10" --footer-font-name "Times" --print-media-type /var/folders/45/2rx5vf4j47jf4hx5157q4q800000gn/T/ResearchSummaryReport-20196712254722.html /var/folders/45/2rx5vf4j47jf4hx5157q4q800000gn/T/ResearchSummaryReport-20196712254722.pdf'' ] })
Error: spawn /bin/sh -c ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:74:11)
```

Can't figure this one out...

Comment: Is there a program named `/bin/sh -c`? Cause the `-c` looks suspiciously like an argument to me, and if it is, should go where arguments go.

Comment: `sh` is just that, no need for `/bin/`, and that `-c` is a runtime argument, and needs to go in the argument array. `spawn('sh', ['-c', '...', ...])`. See the [example in the API docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

child_process.spawn is looking for a file with a path of "/bin/sh -c", which does not exist. You should pass -c as a parameter instead.

Try this:

```
child = child_process.spawn('/bin/sh', ["-c","'" + args.join(' ') + "'"], {stdio: 'inherit'});
```

Comment: Yes that made the error go away.  Now when it runs nothing happens. If I run it in the terminal it DOES do something.  Can't find anything going to stdout or stderr.

Comment: Have you made sure that you are adding child.stdout.on("data", function(data) {}) to actually retrieve data? https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

Comment: You may want to try child_process.spawnSync for an easy way to make sure things are working correctly.https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

Comment: I'm extremely surprised that child_process.spawn was not working for you, but it's a good thing that you have a solution.

Comment: Me too, wondering if it has something to do with the output from the program I am callind...

Comment: if you are not using stdio:inherit, probably you might need to set cwd: process.cwd()